# Lazy loading images in a lwuit list

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am developing an app with LWUIT on J2ME. I have a list that contains images fetched from the web along side some text.

I would like to know how I can lazy load the images so that the form will not freeze while users are trying to interact with it?

Answer (score 1):

Eric Coolman implemented pretty much that in [Codename One](http://gadgets.coolman.ca/lazy-loading-implementing-an-infinite-list-in-codename-one/) which is the next generation for LWUIT. Allot of what he wrote can be applied to LWUIT.

Comment: Thanks Almog, i will visit the site now.